# PHP preg_match_all - extract content from pattern in different order

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm cleaning up some wordpress short codes in my code and I'm looking for a solution that would extract the right values no matter the order of the values.

Example:

```
[Links label="my_label" url="my_url" external="other_value"]
```

If I want to extract my_label, my_url and other_value, I would use the following structure:

```
preg_match_all('/\[Links label=\"(.*?)\" url=\"(.*?)\" external=\"(.*?)\"\]/', $content, $output_array);
```

The problem is that I sometimes have a different order like this:

```
[Links url="my_url" external="other_value" label="my_label"]
```

My previous preg_match_all doesn't work with this. I have tried to put each pattern between (...) or use | but I don't get the expected result. I have seen solutions here to identify strings but I need more than identifying strings, I need to extract values.

It's probably something trivial for a regex expert.

Thanks

Comment: But then your array will be in the different order as well. How would you know URL is the first then?

Comment: @Andreas that's my problem, sometimes url will be first, sometimes it will be something else. I'd like to extract the data no matter the order.

Comment: Are you trying to extract only the values of those attributes ?? May be this is what u want ?  `(\".*?\")` You can check here - https://regex101.com/r/02Rqj6/1

Comment: @rootkonda yes I need to value but I need to know which one is the label, which one is the url, ... I could always recognize them based on content but external and label are alphanumerical and the content could be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the properties could also be a different amount in any order and should start with `[Links` , you can make use of the `\G` anchor. The key is in capture group 1, the value in capture group 2.

```
(?:\[Links|\G(?!^))(?=[^][]*])\h+([^\s=]+)="([^\s"]+)"
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[Links` Match `[Links`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=[^][]*])` Positive lookahead, assert a `]` at the right
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s=]+` Match 1+ times any char except `=` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `="` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\s"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `"` or a whitespace char
- `)"` Close group 2 and match `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0bMQdH/1)

*Example*

```
$re = '/(?:\[Links|\G(?!^))(?=[^][]*])\h+([^\s=]+)="([^\s"]+)"/m';
$str = '[Links label="my_label" url="my_url" external="other_value"]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r($matches);
```

*Output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [Links label="my_label"
            [1] => label
            [2] => my_label
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  url="my_url"
            [1] => url
            [2] => my_url
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  external="other_value"
            [1] => external
            [2] => other_value
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/UIjuK)

Answer (score 2):

What you could (perhaps) do is to not list what key you want to match, just anything before and after the equal sign.
That way you "parse" the string and can later work out what is what.

```
$str = '[Links label="my_label" url="my_url" external="other_value"]';

preg_match("/\[links\s+(.*?)=\"(.*?)\"\s+(.*?)=\"(.*?)\"\s+(.*?)=\"(.*?)\"/i", $str, $match);

unset($match[0]);
foreach(array_chunk($match,2) as $m){
    $res[$m[0]] = $m[1];
}

var_dump($res);
```

This gives you:

```
array(3) {
  ["label"]=>
  string(8) "my_label"
  ["url"]=>
  string(6) "my_url"
  ["external"]=>
  string(11) "other_value"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/H1qGD

But it all depends on if you have more things to parse, then maybe this will match something else also.

Comment: @Vishnu thank you for the edit. I approved it but rather use \s+ in the regex. That will do the same thing but without the extra function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works. But if you just need the values and not their corresponding keys, then you can use the below code as well.

```
$content = '[Links label="my_label" url="my_url" external="other_value"]';
$temp = explode("\"",$content);
$output = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < count($temp); $x++) {
    if($x % 2 != 0) { 
       array_push($output,$temp[$x]);
    }
}
```

The $output array will contain all the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the full overkill route, you could just reuse Wordpress' regexes and processing.

For example:

```
<?php

$res = extract_specific_shortcode('links', $teststring = '[links label="Label" url="https://nisamerica.com/" external="yes" /] '."\n".
'[links label="Label2" url="https://google.com/" external="no"]content[/links]' );

print_r($res);

function extract_specific_shortcode( $tagname, $content ) { 

    $tagname_regex = preg_quote($tagname, '/');

    $wp_shortcode_atts = function( $text ) {
        $atts    = array();
        $pattern = '/([\w-]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"(?:\s|$)|([\w-]+)\s*=\s*\'([^\']*)\'(?:\s|$)|([\w-]+)\s*=\s*([^\s\'"]+)(?:\s|$)|"([^"]*)"(?:\s|$)|\'([^\']*)\'(?:\s|$)|(\S+)(?:\s|$)/';
        $text    = preg_replace( "/[\x{00a0}\x{200b}]+/u", ' ', $text );
        if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $text, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
            foreach ( $match as $m ) {
                if ( ! empty( $m[1] ) ) {
                    $atts[ strtolower( $m[1] ) ] = stripcslashes( $m[2] );
                } elseif ( ! empty( $m[3] ) ) {
                    $atts[ strtolower( $m[3] ) ] = stripcslashes( $m[4] );
                } elseif ( ! empty( $m[5] ) ) {
                    $atts[ strtolower( $m[5] ) ] = stripcslashes( $m[6] );
                } elseif ( isset( $m[7] ) && strlen( $m[7] ) ) {
                    $atts[] = stripcslashes( $m[7] );
                } elseif ( isset( $m[8] ) && strlen( $m[8] ) ) {
                    $atts[] = stripcslashes( $m[8] );
                } elseif ( isset( $m[9] ) ) {
                    $atts[] = stripcslashes( $m[9] );
                }
            }
     
            // Reject any unclosed HTML elements.
            foreach ( $atts as &$value ) {
                if ( false !== strpos( $value, '<' ) ) {
                    if ( 1 !== preg_match( '/^[^<]*+(?:<[^>]*+>[^<]*+)*+$/', $value ) ) {
                        $value = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $atts = ltrim( $text );
        }
     
        return $atts;
    };

    // Taken from wordpress 
    $regex = '/\\['                             // Opening bracket.
        . '(\\[?)'                           // 1: Optional second opening bracket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]].
        . "($tagname_regex)"                     // 2: Shortcode name.
        . '(?![\\w-])'                       // Not followed by word character or hyphen.
        . '('                                // 3: Unroll the loop: Inside the opening shortcode tag.
        .     '[^\\]\\/]*'                   // Not a closing bracket or forward slash.
        .     '(?:'
        .         '\\/(?!\\])'               // A forward slash not followed by a closing bracket.
        .         '[^\\]\\/]*'               // Not a closing bracket or forward slash.
        .     ')*?'
        . ')'
        . '(?:'
        .     '(\\/)'                        // 4: Self closing tag...
        .     '\\]'                          // ...and closing bracket.
        . '|'
        .     '\\]'                          // Closing bracket.
        .     '(?:'
        .         '('                        // 5: Unroll the loop: Optionally, anything between the opening and closing shortcode tags.
        .             '[^\\[]*+'             // Not an opening bracket.
        .             '(?:'
        .                 '\\[(?!\\/\\2\\])' // An opening bracket not followed by the closing shortcode tag.
        .                 '[^\\[]*+'         // Not an opening bracket.
        .             ')*+'
        .         ')'
        .         '\\[\\/\\2\\]'             // Closing shortcode tag.
        .     ')?'
        . ')'
        . '(\\]?)/i';                          // 6: Optional second closing brocket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]].
    // phpcs:enable


    preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $set = [];
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $set[] = [
            'fullmatch' => $match[0],
            'attributes' => $wp_shortcode_atts($match[3]),
        ];
    }
    return $set;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fullmatch] => [links label="Label" url="https://nisamerica.com/" external="yes" /]
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Label
                    [url] => https://nisamerica.com/
                    [external] => yes
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fullmatch] => [links label="Label2" url="https://google.com/" external="no"]content[/links]
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Label2
                    [url] => https://google.com/
                    [external] => no
                )

        )

)
```

The code above is derived from the following functions:

- [get_shortcode_regex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/)
- [shortcode_parse_atts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_parse_atts/)
- [get_shortcode_atts_regex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_atts_regex/)

Like the other solutions posted, WordPress does it's attribute mapping in two parts: Collecting the keys and values and then combining them together after that. Their regex is a little more intense as it handles a few more edge cases than being presented here of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(\b[^"=]+)="([^"]+)"/', $content, $output_array);

$result = array_combine($output_array[1], $output_array[2]);
```